# Which function or file is responsible for initialization of g_37HashSeed

Tags: windows, hash-functions

I'm checking `tcpip.sys` file in IDA and found that in the `.data` part
there is an int called `g_37HashSeed`.
This seed is an input for a hash function that I look into.
Can someone tell me which program or function is
responsible for initializing this seed?

```
.data:00000001C020512C g_37HashSeed    dd ?                    ; DATA XREF: IppSendError+33E↑r
.data:00000001C020512C                                         ; IppFindPath+31↑r ...
.data:00000001C0205130 IppNSWorkerQueue dq ?                   ; DATA XREF: IppResolveNeighbor+31C↑o
.data:00000001C0205130                                         ; IppNeighborSolicitationWorker+2E↑o ...
.data:00000001C0205138 qword_1C0205138 dq ?                    ; DATA XREF: IppResolveNeighbor+315↑r
.data:00000001C0205138                                         ; IppResolveNeighbor+339↑w ...
.data:00000001C0205140 ; KSPIN_LOCK IppNSWorkItemLock
.data:00000001C0205140 IppNSWorkItemLock dq ?                  ; DATA XREF: IppNeighborSetTimeout+253↑o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `g_37HashSeed` variable is initialized in the function `IppInitSharedHashContext`, in the file `tcpip.sys`:

```
IppInitSharedHashContext proc near
sub     rsp, 28h
or      edx, 0FFFFFFFFh
mov     ecx, 1
call    RandomNumber
mov     cs:g_37HashSeed, eax
mov     al, 1
add     rsp, 28h
retn
IppInitSharedHashContext endp
```

The `RandomNumber` function seems to be a simple LCG (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with the parameters `a=1664525, c=1013904223`.

You can find this by yourself by right clicking on `g_37HashSeed` in IDA and select `List cross references to...`.

Comment: Thank you so much.